# e.OriginalSource returns wrong information

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a custom slider, part of a custom control (a colorpicker). The slider is used 4 times for RGBA, when one of the slider change, I need to update colors in other part of the colorpicker (other customcontrol like HueWheel, etc.).

The ColorSlider class :

```
public class ColorSlider : Slider
{
    static ColorSlider()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorSlider), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorSlider)));
    }

    public Color LeftColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(LeftColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LeftColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LeftColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Black));

    public Color RightColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(RightColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RightColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RightColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.White));

    private bool _isPressed = false;
    private Slider _PART_Slider;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _PART_Slider = (Slider)GetTemplateChild("PART_Slider");
        _PART_Slider.ApplyTemplate();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        _isPressed = true;
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            Point position = e.GetPosition(_PART_Slider);
            double d = 1.0d / _PART_Slider.ActualWidth * position.X;
            var p = _PART_Slider.Maximum * d;
            _PART_Slider.Value = p;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        _isPressed = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {  
            Point position = e.GetPosition(_PART_Slider);
            double d = 1.0d / _PART_Slider.ActualWidth * position.X;
            var p = _PART_Slider.Maximum * d;
            _PART_Slider.Value = p;
        }
    }
}
```

And its XAML :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorSlider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorSlider}">
                <Border>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LeftColor}" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=RightColor}" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Slider x:Name="PART_Slider" Maximum="255">
                        <Slider.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="Part_Grid">
                                    <Track Grid.Row="1" Margin="-3,0,-2,0" x:Name="PART_Track" >
                                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerRepeatButtonStyle}" 
                                                          Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" />
                                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerRepeatButtonStyle}" 
                                                          Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" />
                                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <Track.Thumb>
                                            <Thumb x:Name="Part_Thumb" Style="{StaticResource ColorSliderThumbStyle}">
                                                <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TranslateTransform Y="5"/>
                                                </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                            </Thumb>
                                        </Track.Thumb>
                                    </Track>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Slider.Template>
                    </Slider>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Inside my colorpicker class I try to update colors if one of the sliders changed :

```
private void OnSliderValueChanged(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // Avoid endless loop
    if (m_withinChange)
        return;

    m_withinChange = true;
    Console.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource);
    if (e.OriginalSource == m_redColorSlider ||
        e.OriginalSource == m_greenColorSlider ||
        e.OriginalSource == m_blueColorSlider ||
        e.OriginalSource == m_alphaColorSlider)
    {
        Color newColor = GetRgbColor();
        UpdateHsvControlColor(newColor);
        UpdateSelectedColor(newColor);
    }
    else if (e.OriginalSource == m_hueWheel)
    {
        double hue = m_hueWheel.Hue;
        UpdateHsvControlHue(hue);
        Color newColor = GetHsvColor();
        UpdateRgbColors(newColor);
        UpdateSelectedColor(newColor);
    }
    m_withinChange = false;
}

private static void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    ColorPicker colorPicker = (ColorPicker)sender;
    colorPicker.OnSliderValueChanged(e);
}
```

Problem is, the condition `e.OriginalSource == m_redColorSlider` is never true, so the color never gets updated. Indeed, if I do a `Console.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource)` the console shows `"System.Windows.Controls.Slider"` instead of something like `"ColorPicker.ColorSlider"`. But, another control I made called HueWheel (a circular slider, in an other class) is working correctly in this case, but can't find the difference...

Any idea ?

Thank you

EDIT ---

Here is a link to download this little project : [ColorPicker](http://www.filedropper.com/colorpicker_1)

As I'm a total beginner in CustomControl programming, maybe I'm missing some explanation for this problem.

Comment: Arent you missing the sender on `OnSliderValueChanged`? The sender might inidcate the source of the event

Comment: I don't think so because it us working for the HueWheel which is another part of.the custom control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your Slider-Control. **Dont nest a Slider within another Slider**

**XAML**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorSlider}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorSlider}">
                    <Border>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=LeftColor}" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=RightColor}" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Grid x:Name="Part_Grid">
                            <Track Grid.Row="1" Margin="-3,0,-2,0" x:Name="PART_Track" >
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerRepeatButtonStyle}" 
                                                              Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" />
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerRepeatButtonStyle}" 
                                                              Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" />
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Part_Thumb" Style="{StaticResource ColorSliderThumbStyle}">
                                        <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform Y="5"/>
                                        </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                    </Thumb>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Code**

```
public class ColorSlider : Slider {
        static ColorSlider() {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorSlider), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorSlider)));
        }

        #region Dependency Properties

        public Color LeftColor {
            get { return (Color) GetValue(LeftColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LeftColorProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LeftColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Black));

        public Color RightColor {
            get { return (Color) GetValue(RightColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RightColorProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RightColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RightColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.White));

        #endregion


        private bool _isPressed = false;

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
            _isPressed = true;
            if (_isPressed) {
                Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
                double d = 1.0d / this.ActualWidth * position.X;
                var p = this.Maximum * d;
                this.Value = p;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
            _isPressed = false;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (_isPressed) {
                Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
                double d = 1.0d / this.ActualWidth * position.X;
                var p = this.Maximum * d;
                this.Value = p;
            }
        }
    }
```

Since you are already inheriting from slider, you dont have to put another slider inside yourself.

For clearance: You actual control didnt fired any event. The nested slider did

Cheers